# How can I add a watermark or png or bitmap to the background of a CTreeCtrl?

Tags: c++, winapi, listview, mfc, watermark

I would like to have a background image for a list control (CTreeCtrl).  Is this possible and how can I do it?

(This is for a Visual Studio 2008 C++ mfc app)

Answer (score 2):

Hope [this](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/treeview/misc-advanced/article.php/c679) code will help you.

Comment: Nice link but who the hell would like shells as a background image in a list view ?!

Comment: Unfortunately this example does not work at all.  It would also be nice to get the source code and a sample app.  I followed the content and added the code to my project, but it does not work at all.  Oh well.